# How do I use a Chrome Extension to speed a webapp's load times?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Looking for high-level guidance as I'm not sure where I'd even start w/ this.

I'm making a web app where most (if not all) of my users will have installed a Chrome extension I've written.

What I'd like to do is include large libraries in the Chrome Extension, and have the web app load the libs from the extension when the user visits a site.

e.g., both the extension & web app use `React` (same version).

When user visits `www.mywebapp.com`, the extension would inject the React library into the page and skip downloading the script.

Is this possible and/or advisable?

Comment: [Progressive web apps](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) is the tech Google currently develops, promotes, and recommends. Don't you like it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably not a good idea, because you don't directly control updates of your extension. And the two have to be more or less in sync.

Suppose you need to update your site. Then you want to update the extension as well. That's at mercy of Google, and takes time. It's best if such updates are fully controlled by your web app server.

There are much better mechanisms to speed up (subsequent) load time by using client-side caches such as `ApplicationCache`. Here are a few resources to start:

- [A Beginner's Guide to Using the Application Cache @ HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)
- [Your first offline web-app @ Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/your-first-offline-web-app/)
- [Application Cache is a Douchebag](http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag) (for some gotchas)